# How do I prevent my background image from shrinking?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a background image for my bootstrap row. When I resize (make smaller) the browser window, the image shrinks with it.

I am trying to make it so that the image stays in place centered and does not shrink.  So as I am making the browser smaller, the image should stay centered in the page and its edges basically become invisible.

I have the following CSS:

```
.my-bootstrap-row {
    background-image: url(foo.jpg); 
    background-position:fixed; 
    background-size: 100% 100%; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    height:700px;  /* image height is also 700px */
}
```

and following HTML:

```
<div class="row my-bootstrap-row">
   blah blah
</div>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you put fiddle?

Answer (score 4):

Its shrinks Just because you set `background-size: 100% 100%;` Set your `background-size: cover;` and you can also do that for background image looking center `background-image: url(foo.jpg) center center;`

```
.my-bootstrap-row {
background-image: url(foo.jpg) center center no-repeat; 
background-position:fixed; 
background-size: cover; 
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
height:700px;  /* image height is also 700px */
```

Answer (score 2):

According to you code the error is here,

```
.my-bootstrap-row {
    background-image: url(foo.jpg); 
    background-position:fixed; 
    background-size: 100% 100%; //ERROR making the image shrink with the window remove this and set is as cover.
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    height:700px;  /* image height is also 700px */
}
```

Try something like this,

```
.my-bootstrap-row {
    background: url("../images/bg.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

In my code the background properties are in one line and I also added the size property to support other browsers just in case.

Comment: If you want to prevent your background image from shrinking you need to use the property background-size: auto;

Answer (score 1):

Try to do it like this

You are using `background-size: 100% 100%` use `background-size: cover`

Hope this will helps you

```css
.my-bootstrap-row {
    background-image: url(https://www.axure.com/c/attachments/forum/7-0-general-discussion/3919d1401387174-turn-placeholder-widget-into-image-maintain-interactions-screen-shot-2014-05-29-10.46.57-am.png); 
    background-position:fixed; 
    background-size: cover; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    height:700px;  /* image height is also 700px */
    
}
```

```html
<div class="row my-bootstrap-row">
   blah blah
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used `background-size:cover` instead of `background-size:100% 100%`

```css
.my-bootstrap-row {
    background-image: url('https://peterwardhomes.files.wordpress.com/2014/12/goole-area-shot_005.jpg'); 
    background-size: cover; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
 background-position: fixed;
    height:700px;  /* image height is also 700px */

}
```

```html
<div class="row my-bootstrap-row">
   blah blah
</div>
```